# Spark Scala Convert Int Column into Datetime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, databricks

I have Datetime stored in the following format - `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. (Data Type -Long Int)

Sample Data -

[image]

This Temp View - `ingestionView` comes from a DataFrame.
Now I want to introduce a new column `newingestiontime` in the dataframe which is of the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

One of the ways I have tried this is, but it didnt work either -

```
val res = ingestiondatetimeDf.select(col("ingestiontime"), unix_timestamp(col("newingestiontime"), "yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp"))
```

Output -

[image]

Please help me here , and If there is a better way to establish this, I will be delighted to learn new thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_unixtime` & `unix_timestamp`.

Check below code.

```
 scala> df
 .withColumn(
     "newingestiontime",
     from_unixtime(
         unix_timestamp($"ingestiontime".cast("string"),
         "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        )
   )
.show(false)
+--------------+-------------------+
|ingestiontime |newingestiontime   |
+--------------+-------------------+
|20200501230000|2020-05-01 23:00:00|
+--------------+-------------------+
```